# Sqlcmd behaving quite strangely

Tags: batch-file, sqlcmd

This is the script line:

```
Sqlcmd -S SERVER -d DATABASE -v var1="!variable1!" var2="%variable2%" var3=!variable3! var4=%variable4% var5=%variable5% -i "C:\FOLDER\query.sql"
```

It yields two errors as detailed below.

I know that this error:

```
'sqlcmd' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

suggests that the path is not properly set to find the `sqlcmd` function.

However, I've verified that the path is correct. That error generates when executing a batch script from R studio in a script.

I also get this error when running the batch file normally:

```
Sqlcmd: '=': Invalid argument. Enter '-?' for help.
```

Comment: Perhaps `!variable3!` or `%variable4%` or `%variable5%` expand to an empty string? For the first error: what output from `where sqlcmd`?

Comment: @JosefZ They shouldn't output empty strings. `where sqlcmd` outputs: `c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\SQLCMD.EXE`